# ASP.NET MVC 'System.NullReferenceException' in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I clonned old respository of an ***ASP.NET MVC*** project. It uses MySql as its server. When I tried to run the project, it shows NullReference Error when trying to connect to database.

[image: Error Log]

[image: Error ss]

I've make sure the parameter that I sent is not null too.

I've installed **MySql Connector for Visual Studio** and **MySql Connector NET** on my machine.
If you can help or point how to access the error details to identify the problem cause that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Somehow I managed to solve it by updating my MySQL EF Nuget (was 8.0.19) to match the MySql Connector NET Version (now they're both 8.0.26)